# Calculate average with two queries

Tags: sql

I want to calculate an average based on 2 queries:

First query: query1 - Returns the total sum

```
select total from BRANDS_TOTAL;
```

or query1

Second query:

```
select count(distinct BRANDS) from BRANDS_TABLE;
```

or query2

How do i put them together to divide the result?
Something like: `select round(query1 / query2)` ...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can put these in the `FROM` clause:

```
select btot.total / bt.cnt_distinct
from (select total from BRANDS_TOTAL) btot cross join
     (select count(distinct BRANDS) as cnt_distinct from BRANDS_TABLE) bt;
```

In many databases, you could just put these in the `select`:

```
select (select total from BRANDS_TOTAL) btot /
      (select count(distinct BRANDS) as cnt_distinct from BRANDS_TABLE)
```

But not all databases support that.

Finally, be careful about integer division.  Some databases calculate `1/2` as `0` rather than `0.5`.  To fix that, just multiply the first value by `* 1.0`.